# issue with ccGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d 1.01 and applied https://github.com/xemus/cocos2d-GestureRecognizers/archives/master this patch for CCGestureRecognizer. below is my code:

```
CCGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]init]   autorelease];
recognizer = [CCGestureRecognizer CCRecognizerWithRecognizerTargetAction:tapGesture
target:self action:@selector(tapGesture:node:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

and I m getting below error.

```
Ld /Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dfaas-eqrkiqwuooxmcphhvbaoxxodahie/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/dfaas.app/dfaas normal i386
    cd /Users/macbook/Desktop/C_program/dfaas
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dfaas-eqrkiqwuooxmcphhvbaoxxodahie/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dfaas-eqrkiqwuooxmcphhvbaoxxodahie/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dfaas-eqrkiqwuooxmcphhvbaoxxodahie/Build/Intermediates/dfaas.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/dfaas.build/Objects-normal/i386/dfaas.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -lz -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGLES -framework OpenAL -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dfaas-eqrkiqwuooxmcphhvbaoxxodahie/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/dfaas.app/dfaas

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCGestureRecognizer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that CCGestureRecognizer is not linked with your app because it's missing. Looking through the code, there is simply no class named CCGestureRecognizer in that repository. The class is only in this [patch file](https://github.com/xemus/cocos2d-GestureRecognizers/blob/master/cocos2d.patch). So you will have to apply the patch, or just use the UIGestureRecognizer directly (they're really easy to use and [well documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

Btw, [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com) has [gesture recognition already built-in](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Kobold2D/html/interface_k_k_input.html#adacb43ae4eedb06a4d838d951876ddc2). You'll find that even easier to use than the UIGestureRecognizer classes.